# Cannot upgrade App to .net Core 1.0.1 on Linux

Tags: .net-core

After upgrading my app to version 1.0.1 like this in project.json:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "type": "platform",
  "version": "1.0.1"
},
```

This works under Windows but not under Linux.
Under Linux I get this error:

```
Project BackendGems (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Project test (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.1' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /opt/dotnet_cli/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
      1.0.0
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.1'.
SUMMARY: Total: 1 targets, Passed: 0, Failed: 1.
```

I tried to delete the nuget cache and made sure I have the same SDK version `1.0.0-preview2-003121`.

What can possible be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The change that you have done on the `project.json` forces your app to run on a runtime version >=v1.0.1 or else fail.

`dotnet restore` updates the dependencies but not the runtime.

So, you just have to install the 1.0.1 runtime in `/opt/dotnet_cli/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App` as the error message states.

Each linux distro has different installation instruction on .NET site, so it may be your case that you can do something like 'apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1'

But for Debian, I had to do it manually:

- Get the link and download `.NET Core binaries only (v1.0.1)` from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#core

> `$ wget https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=825887 -O dotnet-1.0.1.tar.gz`

- Restore it on `/opt/dotnet_cli/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App`

> `tar zxvf dotnet-1.0.1.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet_cli/`

And now `dotnet run` works as expected.

EDIT: Looks like MS is updating the download page right now, so you will find the file to download labeled as `.NET Core binaries only` now (no mention to 1.0.1). But the file is still the same one.

Comment: that's probably it. For my distro Gentoo I don't have a suitable runtime yet. I wasn't aware however, that the CLI also has it's own host runtime. I think this is strange considering the fact that .net core claims that even runtime parts are just seen as dependency and installed as such.
See `~/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.App/` for example. There seem to be no binaries in this folder however.

Comment: You need to compile your app for that. See the docs for self containing application.